# How can I change the grpc.max_receive_message_length configuration in Google bigtable (nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, bigtable

I am getting 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Received message larger than max (5014229 vs. 4194304) when I call the following get method.

```
const [ row ] = await table.row(key).get();
```

I've tried to pass in grpc.max_receive_message_length when creating the bigtable but it doesn't work. Anyone has idea how to override this 4MB restriction?

```
const { Bigtable } = require('@google-cloud/bigtable');

const options = { 
  'grpc.max_send_message_length': -1, 
  'grpc.max_receive_message_length': -1,
  'grpc.max_message_length': -1
}

const bigtable = new Bigtable({ 
  projectId: dbConfig.projectId, 
  keyFilename: dbConfig.key,
  options
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed using a newer version of bigtable.
Was using "@google-cloud/bigtable": "^2.3.2",
and it works after changing to "@google-cloud/bigtable": "^4.0.2",